# Calculating group percentage in SQL

Tags: sql, sqlite, group-by

I have a sample db table with columns 'team' and 'result' that stores match results 'W' (win) or  'L' (loose) for teams 'A' and 'B':

```
team|result
A   |W
A   |W
A   |W
A   |L
B   |W
B   |W
B   |L
B   |L
```

I can get the number of wins/losses per team by grouping by team and result:

sqlite> select team,result,count(*) from results group by team,result;

```
A|L|1
A|W|3
B|L|2
B|W|2
```

However, I would also like to get a percentage of win/loss per team:

```
A|L|1|25
A|W|3|75
B|L|2|50
B|W|2|50
```

I have not succeeded in figuring out how to do this in SQL. I have managed to do this programmatically with a python programme that queries the db via the sqlite api, then loops over the result set and creates a variable to store the total count per group and then calculate percentage, etc

Can this be achieved directly in SQL?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `SUM()` as an analytic function:

```sql
SELCET team, result, COUNT(*) AS cnt,
       100.0 * COUNT(*) / SUM(COUNT(*)) OVER (PARTITION BY team) AS pct
FROM results
GROUP BY team, result;
```